# The variable in element nth-child using jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, count, jquery-selectors

I'm stuck and I can't overflow counting children using variable and jquery. What I do:

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to click a particular child from the list, and that changed class in the same line of the table.

Something like:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(' + count + ')').click(function() {
    $('table tr:nth-child(' + count + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

But I do not know how to properly use the variable 'count'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$.fn.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get current index of the LI and use it to highlight curresponding table row:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('table tr:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

With `nth-child` you need to add +1: `'table tr:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')'`.

Answer (score 0):

Click li first remove active class and addClass, then will be dynamic for click

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('table tr:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qt584yfe/)